# How to print numbers in ascending order visual basic

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, numbers

I have a program that is supposed to print user inputted numbers in order ascending and descending in two different threads. I have the threads setup, but I am a beginner and I am lost on how to print the numbers in order within their respective threads. This is what I have so far

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()

    Dim A, B, C, D, E, F As String

    A = Console.ReadLine()

    B = Console.ReadLine()

    C = Console.ReadLine()

    D = Console.ReadLine()

    E = Console.ReadLine()

    F = Console.ReadLine()

    Dim Up As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Ascending)

    'Setting Up as a thread

    Up.Start()

    Dim Down As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Decending)

    Down.Start()

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
Sub Ascending()
    Dim A, B, C, D, E, F As Integer

End Sub
Sub Decending()
    Dim A, B, C, D, E, F As Integer

End Sub
End Module
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For whoever downvoted this question - The question is perfectly legitimate and well asked. Just because it is a basic question does not justify a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, you're better inputting the numbers into an array. Then you can use the Array.Sort method to sort into ascending order and then use that and the Array.Reverse method to sort the array and revere it.

```
Dim Numbers() as String

Numbers(0) = Console.ReadLine()
Numbers(1) = Console.ReadLine()
Numbers(2) = Console.ReadLine()
Numbers(3) = Console.ReadLine()
Numbers(4) = Console.ReadLine()
Numbers(5) = Console.ReadLine()
Numbers(6) = Console.ReadLine()

Dim Up As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Ascending)

    'Setting Up as a thread

    Up.Start()

    Dim Down As System.Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Decending)

    Down.Start()

    Console.ReadKey()

Sub Ascending()
    Array.Sort(Numbers)
End Sub

Sub Decending()
    Array.Sort(Numbers)
    Array.Reverse(Numbers)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this helped a lot

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark it as answered by clicking on the tick to the left of the answer - Cheers